# Change Color of Material Inputs on Error

Tags: angular, angular-material2

[image]

I Want to change the md-input color red (same as Country Dropdown in Image) when it is dirty and invalid . I have gone through many articles but didn't find any helpful ..

Answer (score 2):

You need to include below css

```
 .mat-input-invalid .mat-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

.mat-input-invalid .mat-input-ripple {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: No need for that now. New update in angular material has that feature too now

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh Please elaborate. I couldn't find anything on the docs.

Comment: check the link `https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview`

Comment: you can use `<mat-error>` element just below the input box.

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh, what about valid state, I am trying to find a way to change the color to green if the input is valid

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by css, but needs a preparation regarding encapsulation to avoid deprecated variants like `::ng-deep`. A solution is given here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46042645/2692283

Here is a short description for your case:

1. Set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your component:

   ```
   import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
       ...
       encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
   })
   ```

   A more detailed explanation is given here:

   [::ng-deep going to be deprecated - Any alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859784/ng-deep-going-to-be-deprecated-any-alternatives)
2. Now just use css to make it red for your case:

   ```
   /* Sets the underline to red if dirty and invalid */
   .mat-form-field.ng-dirty.ng-invalid .mat-form-field-underline {
     background-color: red;
   }
   /* Sets the label to red if dirty and invalid */
   .mat-form-field.ng-dirty.ng-invalid .mat-form-field-label {
     color: red;
   }
   ```

It should work for Angular 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

Error color is set to your warn color in the theme.

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```