# ::ng-deep going to be deprecated - Any alternatives?

Tags: angular

Doc says:

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.

Since i want to upgrade to new versions without changing the code, whats are the alternatives for the deprecated methods?

Comment: @trichetriche `simply add classes or other selectors to your HTML elements` Angular's styles don't work like that if you try to style DOM nodes within a child component in your template due to their style encapsulation (mimicking shadow DOM in the browser)

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel that's why I asked a [mcve]. And simply remove the encapuslation or use global styles, with only a component selector you can get ride of that pseudo selector.

Comment: @trichetriche `with only a component selector you can get ride of that pseudo selector` yup, as long as you remove the encapsulation

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I'm pretty sure you can do without removing it, using global styles.

Comment: @trichetriche Nope, not if you try to style a DOM node not in your template (i.e. try to change the color of a button found in a child component that your component uses... it breaks the encapsulation). https://plnkr.co/edit/tcD33E5cNjZmPcPncd0N?p=preview

Comment: I'm on phone so I can't see the plunkr, but I've been doing that for over two years now, so I don't really know what you're talking about. Encapsulation adds random attributes to your elements, I don't see how à style sheet could break that.

Comment: @trichetriche same bro... dive in and see what Angular does to the CSS rules

Comment: I'll do that tomorrow then and keep you posted !

Comment: That's what I thought, we were not talking about the same thing. I was talking about global styles, and you didn't. If you declare your styles in the **global** stylesheet with the component selector as a CSS selector, it works.

Comment: @trichetriche yeah, that breaks the philosophy of keeping the styles for a component together in one place tho.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I totally agree with that, but when you look for a workaround, you can't really get picky ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to use in place of ::ng-deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep)

Answer (score 56):

After scouring through the [actual notes](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2015AprJun/att-0307/24-minutes.html) from the [committee meetings](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Webapps/WebComponentsApril2015Meeting) on this stuff, it doesn't look like there is an alternative put forward yet. Using the `::ng-deep` syntax ensures that you let Angular take care of breaking out of the style encapsulation (for DOM nodes in child components in your template) that they are doing for your styles (and not using browser native features, making it more future-proof obviously). I think that note is just to let you know that whenever the actual browser mechanism is put in place they plan on implementing it. I personally wouldn't shy away from using it tho.

The only way forward without using that operator in your CSS is to completely opt out of letting Angular manage the style encapsulation for your component by doing this:

```js
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ...
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

If you do this, your styles become global though, so make sure you prepend each style rule with your component to make sure that they don't leak beyond that. For example, if you have a `MyCustomComponent` component with a selector of `my-custom-component`:

```css
my-custom-component button { ... } /* good */
button { ... } /* bad */
```

Comment: See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49308475/2275011 and comments for more details and solutions.

Comment: it's better to prepend rules with `:host`, instead of `my-custom-component`. also, if your project has SCSS, you can put all the rules inside a `:host` rule like `:host { /* my rules */ }`

Answer (score 2):

One alternative that can work is to include the css styles in your global `styles.scss` file*.

For example, say you want to add a style to the `<div class="mat-form-field-flex">` element that gets generated under a `<mat-form-field>`, you could use `::ng-deep` likewise:

your.component.scss

```
::ng-deep mat-form-field.mat-form-field div.mat-form-field-flex {
  padding: 0 0 0 .75em;
}
```

Or instead, you can change:

styles.scss:

```
mat-form-field.mat-form-field  div.mat-form-field-flex {
  padding: 0 0 0 .75em;
}
```

---

*: This is any file that is added to the styles collection in your `angular.json` file.

```
"styles": [
          "src/theme.scss",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

Comment: yes, this is logical, as the global style file is for the global `index.html` file containing all angular app and components, though this index doesn't have any angular pre-built encapsulations which are equivalent to `ViewEncapsulation.None`.  But don't really think it's a good approach to follow as it's gonna be hard to organize all the app style in the global file unless you create a custom style folder where you put all ng-deep customized styles. and then you import it to the global style file.