# Use of ::ng-deep recommendation in angular

Tags: angular, sass

Is using `::ng-deep` in angular component scss right way of applying styling to third party components like datepicker, multiselect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's recommended to avoid using `ng-deep` as it is marked deprecated.

See here in the angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

There has been raised a question what's the [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859784/ng-deep-going-to-be-deprecated-any-alternatives) here on stackoverflow

Comment: Is there any other way to style those elements? In the alternative post that you mentioned, does not look a better solution to me.

Comment: Apply these styles if really unavoidable in global styles or in parent component using a selector to it's child `my-component > child_component {... !important}` and force it `!important`. But if avoidable in any way avoid doing things like this