# How to change padding in material menu in mat-item-content?

Tags: angular, menu, angular-material

I can't change padding of mat-menu-content. I can't access to it through simple css or ::ngdeep. Any ideas how to do it? I'm quite new to angular :(

everything is inside:

```
<div class="...">
<mat-menu>
  //The rest of code is here, some *ngFor, sub menu
<mat-menu>
```

---

I want to make mat-menu-content padding 0px but I can't do it through simple css or ::ngdeep

```
.mat-menu-content:not(:empty) {
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change `mat-menu-content` by adding

```
::ng-deep .mat-menu-content{
  padding:0px !important;
}
```

working [**`demo`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhpp1c?embed=1&file=app/menu-overview-example.css)

Comment: `ng-deep` is deprecated, see official docs: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: yeah, In the latest Angular it has been deprecated and also please check when I answered the question.

Comment: Yeah sure, no offense. Was just pointing that out since I ended up here with Google. It's been a while since it is deprecated though (example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859784/ng-deep-going-to-be-deprecated-any-alternatives)

Comment: I added an answer that does not need ::ng-deep, but rather uses !important and css selector specificity.

Comment: the .class .mat-menu-content does not work.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid using ngdeep, try this:

1. Apply a class to your menu (using the 'class' input alias: `<mat-menu class="my-class">`)
2. In your css, override angular's .mat-menu-content:

   `.my-class .mat-menu-content { padding: 0 !important; }`

Obviously pick whatever padding you need. This works for me.