# How to style the PrimeNg components?

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, styling

I am using the PrimeNg library in my current project and trying to style the components of this library but the problem is we can not style those components using our normal css classes so for the time being I found out that

1. We can use the `::ng-deep` instead for styling. So I did use this but this is not the legit or proper way of styling these components
2. In-line styling: this is also not a great way of doing styling in a client project

So if anyone could help with this problem how can we style any alternative way of doing this?

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-sidebar {
  width: 285px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 100vh;
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: What I did in the project that is using PrimeNg was to create a global stylesheet for each PrimeNg component and then `@import` it or `@use` it if used by containing components. In this stylesheet I styled e.g. `.p-sidebar { ... }` w/o relying on `::ng-deep` and not inside `:host`

Comment: I dont think it would work or even if this works i dont think so it is the best way of doing so anyways if possible can you just provide code snippet for better understanding may be i am unable to think what you are explaining in actual.                             and ya obviously thanks for the answer.

Comment: :host ::ng-deep is the best way for individual styling of third party components. What makes you think it isn't? If it's just that it's marked deprecated, you can safely ignore that, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859784/ng-deep-going-to-be-deprecated-any-alternatives

Answer (score 0):

```
For styling component with PrimeNg libraries , you should write all your styling classes in **style.css** file . If you write css class in style.css file then there is no need to write .ng-deep:: . So, you can simply move your css from component to style.css class as shown below:-

**style.css file:-**
.p-sidebar {
  width: 285px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 100vh;
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}

Note:- However , if you want to use .ng-deep as the last solution then you can import ViewEncapsulation property of Angular . By including this property , the :host ::ng-deep .p-sidebar class will not affect other components.

in your ts file:-

import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@component{
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
}
```

Comment: ViewEncapsulation.None is generally a worse option than ::ng-deep because it affects *all* styles in your component and it's easy to accidentally override one globally that you didn't want to. ::ng-deep is more explicit about piercing the encapsulation.